# Detecting Promo code in IAP receipt validateion

Tags: ios, swift

In-App Purchase is successfully added in Application

IAP is currently in development mode and I put the IAP Receipt Validation on server end and it's working fine.

Now I want to integrate Promo Codes for IAP. but they can be generated upon approval from Apple (IAP Review)

Question: How would I detect that an Promo Code has been used against a transaction as the receipt validation response coming from Apple Server doesn't contain transaction amount or any promo code field

example:

```
{
  "receipt": {
    "receipt_type": "ProductionSandbox",
    "adam_id": 0,
    "app_item_id": 0,
    "bundle_id": "com.myApp",
    "application_version": "14.06",
    "download_id": 0,
    "version_external_identifier": 0,
    "receipt_creation_date": "2018-09-05 05:18:33 Etc/GMT",
    "receipt_creation_date_ms": "1536124713000",
    "receipt_creation_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:18:33 America/Los_Angeles",
    "request_date": "2018-09-25 04:53:09 Etc/GMT",
    "request_date_ms": "1537851189557",
    "request_date_pst": "2018-09-24 21:53:09 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_purchase_date": "2013-08-01 07:00:00 Etc/GMT",
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1375340400000",
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2013-08-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
    "original_application_version": "1.0",
    "in_app": [
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "com.myApp.testpack",
        "transaction_id": "1000000439689939",
        "original_transaction_id": "1000000439689939",
        "purchase_date": "2018-09-05 05:03:52 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1536123832000",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:03:52 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2018-09-05 05:03:52 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1536123832000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:03:52 America/Los_Angeles",
        "is_trial_period": "false"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "com.myApp.testpack",
        "transaction_id": "1000000439690499",
        "original_transaction_id": "1000000439690499",
        "purchase_date": "2018-09-05 05:09:38 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1536124178000",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:09:38 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2018-09-05 05:09:38 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1536124178000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:09:38 America/Los_Angeles",
        "is_trial_period": "false"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "product_id": "com.myApp.testpack",
        "transaction_id": "1000000439692512",
        "original_transaction_id": "1000000439692512",
        "purchase_date": "2018-09-05 05:18:01 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1536124681000",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:18:01 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2018-09-05 05:18:01 Etc/GMT",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1536124681000",
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-09-04 22:18:01 America/Los_Angeles",
        "is_trial_period": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 0,
  "environment": "Sandbox"
}
```

I just want to store the coupon code which was used during the transaction in my database for some analysis.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any way of knowing from the receipt or within the app itself. You will see a $0 IAP on your sales report from AppStore Connect

Comment: @Paulw11 if that's the case.. is there any API provided by AppStore to fetch the sales report somehow.  Current requirement is to fetch these transaction in database?

Comment: @Paulw11, found the way. anyways thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 mentioned in comments there is no way of knowing from the receipt or within the app itself.

I began searching for ways to fetch details from the App Analytics and found that Apple provides [Reporter](https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/) which can let us download the reports from the App Analytics. This is based in Java. but people have port this to another language also.

**Useful Libraries**:

PHP
https://github.com/fedoco/itc-reporter

Python
https://github.com/fedoco/itc-reporter